# Simple Unit Testing of firebase rules in emulator always fails

Tags: unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to setup unit testing for my firestore rules and I followed the [video tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests) but for some reason `firebase.assertSucceeds.(testDoc.get())` always passes even though I am not allowing it by the security rule.

Security rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Unit test:

```
process.env.FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST = 'localhost:8090';
const assert = require('assert');
const firebase = require('@firebase/testing');

const PROJECT_ID = 'my-proj-id';

describe("Security Rules",()=>{

    it("monkeytest", async()=>{
        const db = firebase.initializeTestApp({projectId:PROJECT_ID}).firestore();
        const testDoc = db.collection("foo").doc('bar');
        await firebase.assertSucceeds(testDoc.get());
    })
});
```

No matter what I change in the security rule this unit test always passes. When I use `firebase.assertFails(testDoc.get())` instead the test always fails no matter what I change.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using emulator or **`firebase tools version 9.6.0`** to check yours, run the command below:

```
firebase tools --version
```

In this version, every changes you made in `firestore.rules` you should restart your emulator to take effect. `Ctrl-C` to cancel the current emulator and to run the it again(*make sure the changes in `firestore.rules` was saved*), by executing the command below:

```
firebase emulators:start
```

Comment: I was using version `9.3.0` and I updated now to `9.6.1`. Same issue and when I now cancel the emulator and run the test again, the test also passes and there is no "client is offline" as before. I am using mocha and `@firebase/testing`

Comment: so for some reason there was a emulator running in the background on port 8080 even though I specify another port in `firebase.json`. The unit test was always testing agains this emulator which means that any changes / restart of the other emulator had no effect. And the bug that the security rule was not updated automatically as you mentioned did not update the emulator at 8080.